# Review showing edit review even for a new user review

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a new to ruby on rails, basically I want one user to have one review and if a user has an review the user gets redirected to edit page, I've got this working for if one user adds a review but if I log in as another user I'm shown a edit page with the user who has a review.

here's my code that I've used in the `review_controller`.

```
def new

    if logged_in?
      #@review = Review.new

      @review = Review.find_by(session[:user_id])

      @review = Review.find_by(product_id: params[:id])


      if @review.blank?

      @review = Review.new(product_id: params[:id], 
                                user_id: User.find(session[:user_id]).id)
      session[:return_to] = nil
    else 
      render action: 'edit'
    end 
    else
      session[:return_to] = request.url
      redirect_to login_path, alert: "You need to login to write a review"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I guess

```
@review = Review.find_by(session[:user_id])
```

should be

```
@review = Review.find_by(user_id: session[:user_id])
```

Second, your second definition of @review overwrites the first one. Consequently, the review will not be blank, if you are visiting the page with the product reviewed by another user.

Comment: thanks! I got it working by doing  @review = Review.find_by(user_id: session[:user_id], product_id: params[:id])